# How to eliminate non consecutive dates based on column values?

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a dataframe with dates and i need to eliminate the non consecutive values, but the way to determine the consecutive status is splitted between two columns as follows:

```
ID | END        | BEG
1  | 9999-12-31 | 2017-07-01
1  | 2017-06-30 | 2016-01-01
1  | 2015-12-31 | 2015-11-12
1  | 2008-07-26 | 2003-02-24
```

For that particular case the expected result would be

```
ID | END        | BEG
1  | 9999-12-31 | 2017-07-01
1  | 2017-06-30 | 2016-01-01
1  | 2015-12-31 | 2015-11-12
```

It can also occurr that the dates (Which are ordered) present this schema:

```
ID | END        | BEG
2  | 9999-12-31 | 2018-04-01
2  | 9999-12-31 | 2017-01-01
2  | 2016-07-31 | 2014-07-15
2  | 2011-08-31 | 2009-01-01
2  | 2008-12-31 | 1991-11-04
```

In this case, since both the first entries have a 9999-12-31 as END we start on the third line and inmediatly find that the following case is not consecutive, so for this particular case only that date remains, leaving as result:

```
ID | END        | BEG
2  | 2016-07-31 | 2014-07-15
```

Is there a way  to do this using dplyr package? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: a first step might be ```library(lubridate); df %>% mutate(days_between = days(BEG - lag(END)))```

Comment: the dataframe has 1.9 M rows so when i use group by with your statement it takes quite a while (I waited a few minutes and had no answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, ymd) %>%
  mutate(
    BEG_lag = lag(BEG),
    cons = END == BEG_lag - days(1)
  ) %>%
  fill(cons, .direction = 'up') %>%
  filter(cons) %>%
  select(1:3)
```

Comment: that fill function is from what package?

Comment: It's from tidyr package.

Comment: Thanks, i was missing that. In the second case, it's also taking the last result, i mean, it returns this:

    `2  | 2016-07-31 | 2014-07-15 
     2  | 2011-08-31 | 2009-01-01
     2  | 2008-12-31 | 1991-11-04`

instead of this:

    `2  | 2016-07-31 | 2014-07-15
     2  | 2011-08-31 | 2009-01-01`

sorry about my formatting skills

Comment: Both cases are correct on my computer. Maybe it's because in your data frame columns `END` and `BEG` are character type. Check my edited solution.